# How to enable compass-import-once in maven

Tags: maven, sass, compass

According to [this](http://www.geodienstencentrum.nl/sass-maven-plugin/dependencies.html), the sass-maven-plugin includes [compass-import-once](https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/tree/master/import-once).

I would like to know how I can enable this feature in my maven project. Relevant excerpt of my pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>nl.geodienstencentrum.maven</groupId>
     <artifactId>sass-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.0-RC2</version>
     <configuration>
         ...
         <useCompass>true</useCompass>
         <gems>
             <gem>compass-import-once</gem>
         </gems>
     </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

When I run `mvn sass:watch`, in the output, the following line is included: "Running with Compass enabled". However, in my `.scss` file,

```
@import "foo"
@import "foo"
```

still causes all the elements in "foo" to be included twice in the compiled css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out. In the `<gem>` tag, what I wanted was not `compass-import-once`, but instead, `compass/import-once/activate`.

And it turns out that `<useCompass>` is not necessary, either. For posterity, the pom.xml should be:

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>nl.geodienstencentrum.maven</groupId>
     <artifactId>sass-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.0-RC2</version>
     <configuration>
         ...
     <gems>
         <gem>compass/import-once/activate</gem>
     </gems>
 </configuration>
```